# Comparing YUI and Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, yui, javascript-framework

I've been using [Ext JS](http://www.extjs.com) as my rich-widget toolkit for a while, but I'm thinking of moving to [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/), partly because of the less restrictive license.

The component-oriented model used in YUI seems quite similar to the one that I've enjoyed so much in Ext JS, but I'm interested in how deep those similarities are. So I'm interested in feedback from people who've used both Ext JS and YUI. What is the same, and what is different? What do I lose by moving to YUI, and what do I gain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think both libraries actually address different needs.

YUI is designed addresses the needs of Yahoo inc. It is very good at building public facing applications where things like graceful degradation, clean markup and accessibility is important.

ExtJS is a very good and well designed full RIA framework that is very firmly targeted at building line of business applications. Features such as a really powerful grid component, strong layout and good professional look and feel.

I've used both quite considerably, although only up to YUI 2.7.0 and have built several full RIA using the frameworks.

Moving an existing application from one to another would be quite differcult as although they share a common ancestor (ExtJS was once YUIext) the frameworks are quite different now.

Comment: Interesting point about public facing vs. line of work applications. We've been using ExtJS for internal stuff so far, but we are thinking about using it for a public facing application - sounds like we may want to go with YUI in that case.

Comment: that's where I kinda a draw the line, it doesn't have to be like that (I'm sure the ExtJS guys would say) but frameworks like YUI and jQuery  seem to be a little better suited to public facing

Comment: That's a very interesting point, I agree 100%. Now that I've been using ExtJS a bit more, I remember the days of trying to use YUI in our business app and I thought it was good and fairly mature, but it was difficult to get it to handle all the little things you might want in a business app. YUI is quite mature, but they don't quite target the same people.

Answer (score 3):

One major difference is that YUI is distributed under the extremely permissive BSD license whereas ExtJS is distributed under a very viral interpretation of the GPL. For instance, with Sencha's interpretation of the GPL, if you write a SOAP or REST interface specifically to talk to an ExtJS front end then your server code must be GPL and you must provide access to the source since you have "distributed" it by granting access over the web. Sencha does provide a commercial license for their code but if you read their docs carefully you will see that they do not allow you to convert code you wrote against GPL Sencha to another license when you switch to the commercial version. (http://www.sencha.com/legal/license-overview)

In short, if your code needs to integrate with proprietary business logic or commercially licensed systems then you must develop using the commercial version of Sencha from the outset.

Answer (score 2):

For me the difference is that YUI is very lightweight and flexible, whereas ExtJS is heavier, with a bigger footprint and more rigid in the way you use it. YUI is great if you know what you're doing in Javascript and want to extend your power; ExtJS is good if you want a UI abstraction layer that you don't have to mess with much ... but if you *do* want to make it do things it wasn't designed to do, it can be a real chore.

Comment: Ext is extremely flexible and powerful if you know how to use it -- it is definitely not "rigid".  I think a fairer statement might be that it has a steeper learning curve, but in my opinion it is an equally powerful framework.

Answer (score 2):

When building a recent application I had the exact same decision to make YUI or Ext JS.

I ended up going with YUI for a few reasons:
YUI 3 is extremely light weight and fast for simple tasks and the lazy loading makes things even faster.

Graceful degradation was important for this app.

Using YUI 2 widgets in YUI 3 is rather easy and with 3.1 literally weeks away that will become even easier.

YUI documentation is unbelievable and the irc chat and forums are very helpful and actually have people from the YUI development team.

Answer (score 2):

In a time when **all applications are migrating to the web**, the clear line drawn by Gareth between public facing and Business app doesn't make sense too me.

I prefer the other answers, like the one of Robusto, and compare both framework on technical/financial grounds.

YUI advantages:

- Free
- Lightweight (HTML + Javascript)
- More efficient
- Easier to learn and understand
- Better documentation and examples
- Larger community

Ext advantages:

- Richer features & components
- Some (undocumented) Server Side driver (like .NET) (although using such libraries on the server seems bad design)

Conclusion:
If your web site doesn't require the extra features provided by ext, go for YUI.

Comment: +1 for "free" as the first advantage in YUI, +1 and for the "undocumented" parts of ExtJs (but i can only vote once) :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used ExtJS a lot yet, still in a learning phase, but for what I was able to do with it, I'm pretty sure that even a little more than 1 year ago when I was doing a lot of YUI dev, it would have been much more challenging and the result would not have been as slick.

It's not too say you shouldn't do it, but my advice to you would be to make some serious research and good prototyping of some of the existing features you have to see if YUI will fit your needs. DON'T just base yourself on the examples and the feel of "Yeah seems that would work".

Answer (score 1):

With the GPLv3, it states that as long as your users are all part of the same legal entity that you do not need to share the source code. The verbiage technically states this as if they are not part of the same legal entity, then you need to provide source. But this doesn't mean Sencha won't change the license later. It also doesn't mean they will either.